# Laravel Direct and Indirect Relationship between same two models

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

This question extends the example  [Eloquent : Working With Pivot Tables](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) provided in the Laravel Documentation.

I need the following relationships in an application:

```
User belongsToMany Role
Role belongsToMany Task
User belongsToMany Task
User belongsToManyThrough Role->Task (Task through Role)
```

- So a user can relate to a `Task` either through a `Role`, or directly.
- All relationships are many-to-many.

The part which is unclear to me is how I need to set these up in the models, so that I can use things such as eager loading to get:

- All Tasks that relate to a user through roles
- All Tasks that relate to a user directly
- All Tasks that relate to a user

For instance, what should x and y be below in order to enable all of these relations?

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function tasks()
    {
        return x;
    }
}

class Task extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem with belongsToManyThrough and I solved it using this code:

```
public function Roles()
{
    $task_ids = DB::table('tasks_users')->where('user_id', $this->id)->lists('task_id');
    $role_ids = DB::table('tasks_roles')->whereIn('task_id', $task_ids )->lists('role_id');
    return Roles::whereIn('id', $role_ids)->get();
}
```

I know it's not using function belongsToManyThrough and it's not the most optimized way but it is working. :)